# Twitter profileImageURL intermittently not loading (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, swift2

I'm using Twitters API to grab a users details including their profile image (TWTRUser.profileImageURL); it works but I find that often the profile image is not loading. At first I assumed it was slow/bad connectivity at my end on an iPhone but it seems to be happening even when I seem to have a fine connection. I'm thinking it might be a quick timeout at Twitters end but can't really diagnose the problem very well.

I'm thinking of caching the last known image to a database via Core Data as a work around, but before I do that I thought I'd ask if I was doing everything correctly / missing something. Here's my Swift 2 code:

```
import TwitterKit

class Session: NSObject {
    class var sharedInstance: Session {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = Session()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }

    var userId: String?
    var userName: String?
    var userScreenName: String?
    var userImage: NSData?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.loadTwitterAccountDetails()
    }

    func loadTwitterAccountDetails(){
        if let session = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session() {
            let client = TWTRAPIClient()

            client.loadUserWithID(session.userID) { (user, error) -> Void in
                if let user = user {
                    self.userId = "Twitter\(user.userID)"
                    self.userName = user.name
                    self.userScreenName = user.screenName
                    let userImageURL = NSURL(string: user.profileImageURL)
                    self.userImage = NSData(contentsOfURL: userImageURL!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts? Anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func loadTwitterAccountDetails(){
        if let session = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session() {
            let client = TWTRAPIClient()

            client.loadUserWithID(session.userID) { (user, error) -> Void in
                if let user = user {[week self]
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                          self.userId = "Twitter\(user.userID)"
                          self.userName = user.name
                          self.userScreenName = user.screenName
                          if let userImageURL = NSURL(string: user.profileImageURL) {
                                self.userImage = NSData(contentsOfURL: userImageURL)
                          }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```